# kafka0.10.2 disk_read_io too high, isr always shrink and expand, client timeout

Tags: apache-kafka

**cluster**: 0.10.2  20brokers
**phenomenon**: add a new consumer and triggered by the peak traffic.

1. the cluster will always adjust the ISR
2. disk_read_io rose high
   [image]
3. the client will appear timeout
4. broker fetchreplica link closed. broker logs:
   `Attempting to send response via channel for which there there no open connection, connection id`

**Questions**:
     
1. after check the source code i found this `// if the selector closed the connection because it was idle for too long.` What is the reason for this idle?  disk IO waiting time is too long, or to say that there are other cases of the initiative to shut down

2. Frequent switching ISR consumption of network traffic is much more than normal consumer traffic, why is that

Comment: It's kind of performance issue,  too much consumer output